# change classes in android sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I want to use some special classes about Bluetooth low energy and 
a company send me a directory "classes" with all that stuff.

I included this directory in eclipse, but i think its not working right, because eclipse doesnt know one special method of the sourcecode (of the company), which i added with import function as a project in eclipse.

Is there another possibility to add new classes to android? Or has somoeone an idea, what i´m doing wrong?

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html).  Make a library project from the classes you want to incorporate and then include it as a referenced library.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do i include the classes in the library project?? Import offers serveral ways.

Comment: My answer is not technically correct.  If you follow the link and scroll down, there are instructions to include one project into another one as a library project.  Start a generic project with a name like com.blah.library and add your classes to this generic project.  Then follow the instructions to include that generic project as a library in your main project

Comment: "add your classes to this project."

Comment: I edited my comment to try to make it more clear.  Make a generic project with the classes you want to include.  Then include that generic project as a library project.  That is the only way I know, unless the classes you have are in a jar file?

Comment: "Make a generic project with the classes." There are about a few hundred classes. How should i import them?